# Method in stack trace is shown to be invoked from block, while it is not true in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have stack trace for EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS, and i am currently investigating this issue. However what surprises me most is that stack trace shows block invocation, while method is not called from block but rather from URLSession delegate method.

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1814d01a0 objc_retain + 16
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1814d0218 objc_storeStrong + 44
2  App                        0x1004644e8 -[FCProgressIndicator animateProgressViewToProgress:] (FCProgressIndicator.m:85)
3  App                        0x10046a560 -[FCSeriesListCollectionViewCell updateForItem:] (FCSeriesListCollectionViewCell.m:156)
4  App                        0x1003da4a8 __54-[FCFilmDownloadService notifyListenersForItemUpdate:]_block_invoke (FCFilmDownloadService.m:295)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x181becaa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x181beca60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x181bf965c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1822a3070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1822a0bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1821c0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
11 GraphicsServices               0x1841a6020 GSEventRunModal + 100
12 UIKit                          0x18c1e0758 UIApplicationMain + 236
13 App                        0x1004a707c main (main.m:14)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x181c51fc0 start + 4
```

Actual code is:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

    NSString *downloadUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.absoluteString;
    FCDownloadableFilm *item = self.downloads[downloadUrl];

    /*Processing data */

    [self notifyListenersForItemUpdate:item];
}

- (void)notifyListenersForItemUpdate:(FCDownloadableFilm *) item {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSSet *listeners = [self.listeners[item.url] copy];
        for (id <FCFilmDownloadServiceProtocol> listener in listeners) {
            [listener updateForItem: item];
        }
    });
}
```

What can cause stack trace to show that method notifyListenersForItemUpdate is called from block while it is not?

Comment: The call stack includes all of the runtime code, mostly stuff whose source you never see.  The way to diagnose this is to set an exception breakpoint and rerun.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace does not show that `notifyListenersForItemUpdate` has been called from a block. It is a trace for `updateForItem` which was called from a block inside `notifyListenersForItemUpdate`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

(this one)

The stack trace says that a main loop is being processed and on it there is a block that is declared in `[FCFilmDownloadService notifyListenersForItemUpdate:]`.

Comment: Yes, i see now.